# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working Swift 4 SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` so it executes a function when the user swipes right on the screen in an `SKScene`. This is my code

I declare it, at the top of the scene.

```
let swiperight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` function

```
    swiperight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.swipedRight));
    swiperight.direction = .right;
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swiperight);
```

and then the function to be executed

```
@objc func swipedRight() {

    print("Object has been swiped right")

}
```

However, when I run my app and swipe right on the scene, nothing happens, there is no console output whatsoever.

I'm using swift 4, SpriteKit and Xcode 9.2. I'm running the app on my iPhone 6s running the latest non-beta IOS.

Comment: change to `#selector(swipedRight)`.

Comment: doesn't work when I did that

Comment: Without knowing what your view hierarchy looks like I'd suggest checking to see if some subView is "stealing" the touches.  If there is a subview with `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` then that will prevent your superview (`self.view`) from receiving the touches from your gesture.

Comment: I have no subviews I'm aware of but I do have SKScenes how do I make sure it is top of the hierarachy

Comment: I never use SpriteKit so I'm not super well-versed on the Cocoa Touch objects for it, but basically what I'm talking about with subviews is this: If you have just a blank scene with nothing in it then you have 0 subviews.  If you add a label or a sprite or imageView or something - those are subviews.  If you have anything like that it may be stealing touches.

Comment: Also I notice that `self.view` is an optional (which is why you put that ? in there), so maybe the `.view` property is nil.  That would ALSO cause this code to fail.  Again - I don't know SpriteKit well enough to help out with that very much.

Comment: When I put ! it crashes and says the view is nil

Comment: why is my view nil

Comment: There you go.  That answers it.

Comment: From the docs on the `view` attribute: `To present a scene, you call the presentScene(_:) method or presentScene(_:transition:) method on the SKView class. If the scene is not currently presented, this property holds nil.`

Comment: When I change it to self.view!. it shows this fatal error:

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The scene is presented when the app loads in the GameViewController.swift file

Comment: Again - I don't know what I'm doing with SpriteKit, but it seems you should move your `viewDidLoad` code into `func didMove(to view: SKView)` instead.

Comment: How do I make my scene not nil

Comment: Why are you even trying to add a gesture recognizer to view controller's view when you want the user to swipe screen on game view (SKView)?  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should be presenting your scene like so:

Inside your viewcontroller, declare your scenes at the top E.G.

```
var mainMenu: MainMenu?
```

Override the viewDidLoad method and present your scene as so: (where your SKScene file is called MainMenu.sks)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        mainMenu = MainMenu(fileNamed: "MainMenu")
        mainMenu?.scaleMode = .fill
        view.presentScene(mainMenu)
     }
}
```

Make sure the scene your presenting is of type SKScene

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class MainMenu: SKScene {

}
```

Make sure your viewControllers view is of type SKView.
For example my storyboard looks like so.

[image]

After the scene is presented, set up your gesture recognizer in the didMoveTo method as this is called after the scene is presented which is what you want. Whereas viewDidLoad is called before the view is presented.

If you don't have an sks file then you will have to present your scene as:

```
 scene = MainMenu(size: (view.bounds.size))
```

and the scene you are presenting will have to look like:

```
class MainMenu: SKScene {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder) is not used in this app")
  }

  override init(size: CGSize) {
      super.init(size: size)
      anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
      //Setup your sknodes in here.
  }

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
       action:#selector(swipedRight))
      swipeRight.direction = .right
      view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
  }

  @objc func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
      print("swiped right")
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an .sks file just a skscene in a .swift file. Can I just put in that name instead

Comment: You can but it's a little different, i've updated my answer. Bare in mind that doing it without sks files means you won't have access to the scene editor. This means that you will be doing everything in code including your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try conforming your SKScene to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and setting the `swiperight.delegate` property to your scene. This will make sure that even though you are adding the gesture recognizer to you view, the handling of the gesture is "delegated" to your Scene.